# Show related fields in drill downs for Excel PowerPivot

Tags: excel, excel-2013, powerpivot

We have built a data model in PowerPivot for Excel 2013. All of the data tables currently live in Excel.

Let's assume we have a basic "Sales" facts table and a "Products" dimensions table.  Both tables have the field "ProductID" and are related through that field.

If I build an Excel Pivot Table using that data model, then show the measure "GrossSales" in the pivot table, then double click on that measure in the Pivot Table, I'll get a drill down report.

It will display the top 1000 rows for the measure I selected, but the field "ProductID" which relates two tables is not shown. In our testing, this appears to happen for every relating field.

What gives? Is there anyway to get related fields to show up in the drill down reports?

Let me know if the language or semantics are unclear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked fields are usually not shown when Drill Down. To be able to show it create a new Calculated Columns in "Sales" table which is just a duplicate of ProductID.